# How to calculate bandwidth requirements for rosserial link?

Tags: ros, rosserial, bandwidth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are beginning to prototype a small robot with differential drive, an IMU, and multiple sensors. For the first iteration we plan to put an Arduino with rosserial on the robot and run ROS on a PC. I want to calculate the bandwidth needed for the expected message traffic to determine if rosserial will work for us or if we need to use a different approach, however I can't find any references to the size of ROS messages *once they've been serialized.*

Can anyone give me some advice on how to approach **calculating** this rather than running a simulation and measuring the bandwidth?

Cheers,
Mike

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197748/how-to-calculate-bandwidth-requirements-for-rosserial-link?/) by [MikeH](https://answers.ros.org/users/20702/mikeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-11-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-19**:
Nice question. Would perhaps be a good candidate for a feature request on the [rosserial](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial) tracker: a tool that could automatically do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Serialized messages in ROS are roughly the size that you'd expect them to be; that is, an int64 is 8 bytes, an float32 is 4 bytes, etc. Strings and variable-length arrays are serialized as a 4-byte length followed by the contents (no null terminator). Fixed-size arrays are serialized as a sequence of data, without the length. There is no padding.

I believe the rosserial protocol adds a bit of overhead because it transmits a topic ID along with each message; this should be  well-documented in the rosserial protocol docs.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1